PDF for binary sequences generated by the greatest integer function
If x is a positive irrational number, then the sequence whose n-th term is the greatest integer in (n+1)x  minus the greatest integer in nx  which, as you may know, is equal to the greatest integer in x OR to [the greatest integer in x] plus 1. Thus, it is a sequence made up of two different integers. What is the probability of occurrence for these two possibilities? The probabilities p and q will, of course depend on x. Choose x = pi or any irrational number you like and determine p and q theoretically, not by use of a computer.

Please use MathJax in writing your question. You can find a guide here.
